# Remove last character from the end of a Liquid loop

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've got a loop here pulling out some metafield information, and in the loop theres a  ", " separating each item that gets looped through.
Is there a way to trim the final character of the loop to avoid the trailing comma?
Cheers!

```
<b>Grapes:</b> {% for grape in product.metafields.custom.grapes.value %} <a href="/collection/{{ grape | handleize }} }}">{{ grape }}</a>, {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [unless](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags#unless) to check the [last index](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#forloop) of the loop and like this

```
<b>Grapes:</b> 
{% for grape in product.metafields.custom.grapes.value %} 
  <a href="/collection/{{ grape | handleize }} }}">{{ grape }}</a>
  {% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```